# FCM token returns null in android nougat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-7.0-nougat

FCM token not generated in Android Nougat device(Moto,Sony & Huawei) when installed my app FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() returns null, But FCM token generated in Emulator(Nougat) and below Nougat versions.

Answer (score 1):

When do you call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`?
You need to wait in a Service extending `FirebaseInstanceIdService` for the `onTokenRefresh` callback. This is the moment, where your Token is available.

```
public class FcmTokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    try {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (refreshedToken != null) {
            Log.i("FCM", String.format("Received new registration token from Firebase: token=\"%s\";", refreshedToken));
            // ... forward the new token to some point in your app to store it
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Register the service in your manifest:

```
    <service android:name=".services.FcmTokenService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And this should be the **last** line in your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```