# Firebase token is always null in Android Nougat 7.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-7.0-nougat

I have done all the things required like registering InstanceIDService service in manifest, adding plugins etc.
Issue is only in devices with nougat OS (I have tested it on other devices its working like a charm).

In short this line of code returns null in Nougat:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202095/fcm-token-returns-null-in-android-nougat and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517860/how-to-handle-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-null

Check this solutions. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Could you also verify if the `onTokenRefresh()` is not triggered after sometime?

Comment: thanks a lot for you time @AL. it never triggered so far

Comment: thanks a lot for you time @MaharithAdityaSS I already skimed through stackoverflow but nothing wokred currenlty i am testing on emulator and i thing i should test it now on real device

Comment: i think issue is that emulator doesn't come with play services so now i am trying to install play services and will let you know if it works @MaharithAdityaSS

Comment: @AdeelTurk the FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() works in my emulator which has no play services

Comment: ahan @MaharithAdityaSS , have you tried it on 7.1 emulator ? and i am using genymotion emulator

Comment: I'll let you know adeel I tried in lower version

Comment: it will be a great favor aditya

Comment: For intellectual property reasons, Google Play Services are not included by default in Genymotion virtual devices. However, if you really need them, you can use the packages provided by OpenGapps. @MaharithAdityaSS  
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services

Comment: I know to add play service in Genymotion. I'll Let you Know if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142241/discussion-between-adeel-turk-and-maharith-aditya-s-s).

Comment: Any solutions guys?

Comment: @Khemu are you testing on emulator?

Comment: No i am testing on device.